# helm upgrade --install: Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, helm3

I am trying to download a release of the aws-efs-csi-driver, but I'm getting the following error

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "http://localhost:8080/version": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

I tried `export KUBECONFIG=/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml`

I tried `kubectl config view --raw >~/.kube/config`

Both resulted in the same error as when they were not added. I'm new to helm and EKS. Looking for any suggestions, thanks!

````
helm repo add aws-efs-csi-driver https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-efs-csi-driver/

helm repo update --kubeconfig ./cluster_config

kubectl config view --raw >~/.kube/config

helm upgrade -i aws-efs-csi-driver aws-efs-csi-driver/aws-efs-csi-driver \
    --namespace kube-system \
    --set image.repository=602401143452.dkr.ecr.$1.amazonaws.com/eks/aws-efs-csi-driver \
    --set controller.serviceAccount.create=false \
    --set controller.serviceAccount.name=efs-csi-controller-sa ```
````

Comment: I think I just need to set the right kubeconfig location :facepalm ... will close if fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `--kube-config` parameter in your command and point it to the existing kubeconfig file that you've created in step 3 at `~/.kube/config`. Like

```
helm upgrade -i aws-efs-csi-driver aws-efs-csi-driver/aws-efs-csi-driver \
    --namespace kube-system \
    --set image.repository=602401143452.dkr.ecr.$1.amazonaws.com/eks/aws-efs-csi-driver \
    --set controller.serviceAccount.create=false \
    --set controller.serviceAccount.name=efs-csi-controller-sa
    --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your `kubeconfig` file.

---

Method 1 (`eksctl`):

```bash
eksctl utils write-kubeconfig --cluster <Cluster-Name>
```

To get your cluster name:

```bash
eksctl get cluster
```

---

Method 2 (`aws CLI`):

```bash
aws eks --region <Your-EKS-Region> update-kubeconfig --name <Cluster-Name>
```

To get your cluster name:

```bash
aws eks list-clusters
```

---

After this, you won't get this error again.